# OS Fingerprinting difficulties with nmap and zenmap

Tags: nmap, os-fingerprinting

I am a college student and I am doing a project on information gathering and I am having some difficulties when I run nmap and zenmap for OS fingerprinting.

I get some results that I don't understand, searched the results but found nothing can anyone help me to understand what British Gas is?

I am trying to scan a website.

[image: here are the results from nmap]

Comment: please do not post images of text - copy/paste the text and use code formatting

Comment: when I google "british gas gs z3 data logger" I get hits explaining it

Answer (score 3):

The fingerprint for this match in the `nmap-os-db` file looks like this:

```
# GS-Z3 Data logger, connected to an Energy Display Meter offered by www.energydisplaymeter.co.uk. BGB WebRTU Z3. Firmware Version : 2.05.03 (19), Config Filename: BGBConfig_07_01.bin
Fingerprint British Gas GS-Z3 data logger
Class British Gas | embedded || storage-misc
SEQ(CI=I%II=RI)
OPS(R=N)
WIN(R=N)
ECN(R=N)
T1(R=N)
T2(R=N)
T3(R=N)
T4(R=Y%DF=N%T=FA-104%TG=FF%W=800%S=A+%A=S%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)
T5(R=Y%DF=N%T=FA-104%TG=FF%W=800%S=A%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)
T6(R=Y%DF=N%T=FA-104%TG=FF%W=800%S=A%A=S%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)
T7(R=Y%DF=N%T=FA-104%TG=FF%W=800%S=A%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)
U1(DF=N%T=FA-104%TG=FF%IPL=38%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)
IE(DFI=S%T=FA-104%TG=FF%CD=S)
```

All those `R=N` lines mean that no response was received. Note that Nmap tells you this also: `OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port`

This, combined with the [`tcpwrapped`](https://secwiki.org/w/FAQ_tcpwrapped) version line, indicates that either the link between you and the system is faulty (many dropped packets and closed connections), or there is something between you and the target that is filtering and manipulating connections.